# Is it possible to persist a Volley API request using android-priority-jobqueue library and when it returns Error or the Job object goes to onCancel?

Tags: android, android-volley, jobs

I created a Job object that would call an API Request. But I am not exactly understanding the lifecycle of the Job object.

Here is what I want to happen

1. I want the API Request to be sent when there is an Internet Connection, if not it will then persist it to be sent when there is an Internet Connection.
2. If ever the API Request fails because in the middle of the request it loses Internet Connection or an error occurs, I want it to be created and queued again.
3. I also want the Job to be persisted and will only be removed from the JobManager queue when it returns a result either a successful or error response.
4. How do you cancel a Job within itself anyway?

Here is my class :

```
public class SampleRequestJob extends Job implements APIRequestListener {
    public static final int PRIORITY = 1;

    int id;

    public SampleRequestJob(Context context, String id) {
        super(new Params(PRIORITY).requireNetwork().persist());
        this.id = id;        
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdded() {
        // TODO : Show progress dialog in notifications
    }

    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Throwable {
        // call API Request
        RequestManager.sampleApiRequest(id).setResultListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldReRunOnThrowable(Throwable throwable) {
        // should it really be false? I don't know the conditions of this method
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRequestSuccess(APIRequestType type, JsonNode response) {
        // TODO : Hide progress dialog in notifications
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRequestError(APIRequestType type, VolleyError error) {
        // TODO : Hide progress dialog in notifications, show error in notification panel. 
        // If error is timeout, no connection error, network error, or server error create job and add to jobmanager queue again
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your 'request' object `Serializable`, it would persist that and restore once the given arguments have passed (connection restored).
2. You can define a retry count on the `Job` (`getRetryLimit`). For a retry to trigger, there must be an exception thrown inside `onRun`. Else, you could post/broadcast and event to a component that would just re-queue the object again.
3. The job will be removed once `onRun` successfully finished, so just making sure that no exception is thrown within it should suffice.
4. Take a look [here](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue/wiki/Canceling-Jobs). Again, either an exception or an event is posted to trigger.

Hope that helps.